# Как сделать что бы экземпляр Vue работал со всей страницей?

Tags: javascript, frontend, vue.js

Я не хочу перерисовывать через Vue всю страницу, но у меня есть компоненты в разных частях страницы, которые должны работать. Поэтому я создал экземпляр

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: 'main2',
});
```

main2 - это корневой элемент моей страницы, что бы все компоненты работали. Перед этим я также зарегистрировал компоненты. И всё вроде работает. Но возникает ошибка **"Error compiling template"** . Как я понимаю это из-за того, что я не указал template для всей страницы в которая находится внутри main2. Но мне не нужно перерисовывать всю страницу, а только зарегистрированные компоненты . **Как можно сделать, что бы Vue отслеживала все компоненты на странице, но при этом не требовала шаблона страницы(в компонентах шаблоны есть)?**

*Это обычный сайт, а не одностраничное приложение*

Comment: А почему не использовать как обычно? Vue очень умен и при перерисовке задействует только измененную часть. Там очень все оптимизировано.
Покажите ваш код. Хотя бы пример, чтоб понять где ошибка у вас.

Comment: И что такое *main2*? Может вам нужен *#main2*?

Comment: @yarkov_aleksei , Да точнее #main2. Идея в том, что этот код с компонентами должен работать на всех страницах, а шаблоны страниц разные, а вот шаблоны компонент на этих страницах одинаковые. Ну и + страница большая, и не хочу без надобности добавлять этот шаблон в js, что бы он окончательно не рассбух. (У меня не single page), сервер отдаёт страницу целиком, а на js нужно только динамические элементы сделать)

Comment: В принципе с этой ошибкой даже всё работает, может её как то скрыть можно? Хотя в идеале конечно хотелось бы от неё вообще избавиться...

Comment: Ну по прежнему демо очень не хватает для полной картины

Comment: @yarkov_aleksei , Ну я просто не хочу сюда кучу кода выкидывать, которая только больше всех запутает. Просто есть html страница. там где нужны компоненты в вписан атрибут is="name" - это разные выпадающие списки, и другой интерактив. И в коне страницы(что бы попали все компоненты, указан id #main2, через него и монтирую экземляр vue).

Comment: Если упростить, то у меня примерно такой html -<div id="main">
  <div is="test">Это тест</div>
  <p>бох знает что</p>
  <div is="test2">Это тест2</div>
</div>

Comment: @yarkov_aleksei , и такой js var test = {
  "template": "<div>{{test}}</div>",
  "data": function(){
     return {
            "test": "Сработал первый компонент",
        };
  }
}

var test2 = {
  "template": "<div>{{test2}}</div>",
  "data": function(){
     return {
            "test2": "Сработал второй компонент",
        };
  }
}

Vue.component('test', test);
Vue.component('test2', test2);

var app = new Vue({

    el: '#main'
});